# HTML5, jQuery,... >> Smooth touch-compatible drag and drop / input range slider solution anyone?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, slider, touch

Can anybody help out and recommend a touch-compatible solution for drag and drop based UI elements?

I'm currently looking for an input range slider, similar to
`HTML5 input range`
or
http://jqueryui.com/slider.

While native HTML5 is causing too many troubles (in older browsers and on touchscreens),
i would go for jQuery.
So far, so good - but the overall performance of jQuery drag and drop events is not satisfying, since there is always some kind of delay when dragging objects.
In the slider example, the cursor (and/or finger on touch devices) is always a couple of pixles ahead, especially when doing fast moves.

Are there any alternatives, plug-ins, hacks,... out there, which may help out?
Or is there any way to speed up jQuery's drag and drop functionality?

Comment: I'm also interested :-)

Comment: Did you see this one? http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

Answer (score 0):

hammer.js,maybe :  http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

Try to do a slide on the window of the website (with mouse or finger), hope it answers